# Calling parent method in typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I just started to program in typescript with KnockoutJS and I must confess I don't know design patterns that I think would be super useful here. Because, well- I need a pattern. I want to execute the function from the parent class, yet I don't know what's the best way to achieve this, shall I rather pass along whole object to the children or make some subscriber/listener job here? I don't know really, counting for help. Thank You. Below shortened code:

```
module Desktop {

    export class Note {
        public message: any;
        private duration: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        private timer: number;

        constructor(message: any) {
            this.message = message;
            this.duration = ko.observable(message.duration || 'short');
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => !!THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL killNote!!, 8000); //time enum
        }
    }

    export class NotificationsVM {
        public notes: KnockoutObservableArray<Note>;

        constructor() {
            this.notes = ko.observableArray([]);
            //...
        }

        public addNote(msg) {
            this.notes.push(new Note(msg));
        }

        public killNote(e) {
            this.notes.remove(e);
        }
    }
}




    <!-- ko with: notificationsVM -->
    <aside data-bind="foreach: notes">
        <div>
            ...
        </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

In short: after certain amount of time specified differently for each note I want to kill it (remove from notes array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after certain amount of time specified differently for each note I want to kill it

Functions are first class variables in javascript. So just pass it in :

```
module Desktop {

    export class Note {
        public message: any;
        private duration: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        private timer: number;

        constructor(message: any, killNote) {
            this.message = message;
            this.duration = ko.observable(message.duration || 'short');
            this.timer = setTimeout(() => killNote({}), 8000); //time enum
        }
    }

    export class NotificationsVM {
        public notes: KnockoutObservableArray<Note>;

        constructor() {
            this.notes = ko.observableArray([]);
            //...
        }

        public addNote(msg) {
            this.notes.push(new Note(msg, (e)=>killNote(e)));
        }

        public killNote(e) {
            this.notes.remove(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help @basarat :) Is there any difference if I pass the whole object instead of function?

    `this.notes.push(new Note(msg, this));`

Comment: @MaciejKwas one difference is that `Note` would then rely on `NotificationsVM`. That's a bad thing because it makes your code difficult to change. For example, what if you wanted to use `Note` with something other than `NotificationsVM`... now what do you do? Btw, I would do something similar, but like this so that functionality isn't hidden in the constructor: `var note = new Note(msg); note.onDelete(() => this.killNote(note)); note.startTimer(); this.notes.push(note);`